# Function convert from the position to the element

Tags: ocaml

I have this list combine : `list + undefined list`
I write this function to return the element from there position.

```
let name_of_num list undefined_list len_undefined k =
  if k < len_undefined then List.nth undefined_list k else
    List.nth list (k - len_undefined)

val name_of_num : 'a list -> 'a list -> int -> int -> 'a
```

But my problem is that when I apply to my function the list has different type from undefined list. So this function cannot pass the compiler. where undefined is a list of string.

```
let len_undefined xsds = List.length (undefined xsds)

let xsds_of_int xsds =
List.map (List.map (name_of_num xsds undefined (len_undefined xsds)))
```

`xsds` has type `xsds` in my program. If I replaced `undefined` to `xsds` like this function:

```
let xsds_of_int xsds =
List.map (List.map (name_of_num xsds xsds (len_undefined xsds)))
```

it works. How can I write the second condition when `k < len_undefined` ?

```
let name_of_num list len_undefined k =
  if k < len_undefined then ??? else
    List.nth list (k - len_undefined)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What you ask for seems to be impossible.  You'd like to supply two lists of different types.  But your function sometimes returns an element of `list` and sometimes returns an element of `undefined_list`.  Since OCaml is a strongly typed language, a function must always return values of the same type.  It follows that `list` and `undefined_list` must have the same type.

It's hard to know what to suggest without understanding your requirements.  However, it's very easy to define a *new* type that combines any two types you like.  (Or any finite number of types.)

```
type either = A of typea | B of typeb
```

The value (A x) represents a value of `typea` and the value (B y) represents a value of `typeb`.  But these two values are the same type, type `either`.

You would then define `name_of_num` to take two lists of different types, but it would return the type `either`.  If you want to get fancier you can define `either` as a parametrized type, which would allow `name_of_num` to be polymorphic.  Whether this is a good thing to do depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

I'm not sure this solves your problem, but I hope it helps.

**Edit**

Here's how your function would look if you use the `either` type.  I'll
use `int` for one type and `string` for the other.

```
type either = A of int | B of string

let name_of_num list undefined_list len_undefined k =
  if k < len_undefined then
    (B (List.nth undefined_list k))
  else
    (A (List.nth list (k - len_undefined)))

val name_of_num : int list -> string list -> int -> int -> either = <fun>
#
```

**Edit 2**

It strikes me that you might want to use an exception to solve your problem.  If you're trying to fill in a matrix of mapped values, and if out-of-range inputs are rare (and indicative of an error), you can just raise an exception when you see a bad input.  Caller can catch the exception and decide what to do.  Then your `name_of_num` function would always return `xsd`.  (If it sees a bad value it doesn't return at all.)

Comment: What if it never go to undefined list? Is it possible to have this function with this case?

Comment: If your function *always* returns an element from `list` and never from `undefined_list` then the lists can have two different types, and the function would still be well formed.  But this doesn't make a lot of sense (to me).  Also, the compiler has to be able to tell statically that `undefined_list` is never used.

Comment: `type either = A of Xsd.xsd | B of string`

`let name_of_num (xsds: 'A list) (undefined: 'B list) len_undefined k = if k < len_undefined then List.nth undefined k else
  List.nth xsds (k + len_undefined)` it still return an string list instead of xsd type I want.

Comment: If you use `either` the function will return `either`, it won't return the `xsd` type.  See **Edit** above.  You can't return the `xsd` type if you also want to return `string` at other times.  OCaml simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: Your Edit 2 is what I was doing. But I think the undefined list actually used because when I run the program, it raise that exception. And 'either' type is a solution in this case, but the problem is that I want to convert the type xsds ('a) type not either type.

Comment: I had fixed this problem by converting my undefined list to xsd type. Thank you for your help.